# preg_replace_callback quirk? doesn't match a certain type of string

Tags: php, regex

Is this some quirk with the preg_replace_callback function or something?

The full code is really complex but I'll post the specific problem here which I found after alot of debugging, a specific type of tag doesn't get matched at all, any ideas why this could be?

```
preg_replace_callback('/(?:<del>(.|\n)*?<\/del>)|(?:<ins>(.|\n)*?<\/ins>)|(?P<DOT>[\s\S])/', function($match) {
//does something and runs fully for every tag except the tag below 
}
```

it matches other tags including html inside del tags but this sort of img tag isn't matched for some reason and the code just crashes at this point without calling the callback function at all. I checked using an online regex tester that this should match.

```
<del><img src="?tpl=img&amp;url=1/68/thumb/Back-View-Of-Statue-Of-Liberty-With-Full-Moon.jpg" srcset="?tpl=img&amp;url=1/68/thumb/Back-View-Of-Statue-Of-Liberty-With-Full-Moon.jpg 320w,?tpl=img&amp;url=1/68/med/Back-View-Of-Statue-Of-Liberty-With-Full-Moon.jpg 480w,?tpl=img&amp;url=1/68/large/Back-View-Of-Statue-Of-Liberty-With-Full-Moon.jpg 640w" sizes="(max-width:320px) 320px, (max-width:480px) 480px, 640px"></del>
```

Just asking incase anyone has a clue or could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Never use `(.|\n)*?` in any regex except Lucene. There are other, more efficient ways to match any char. In PHP, use a mere `.` and add an `s` modifier after the trailing regex delimiter. But do not try this, parse HTML with a DOM parser, not regex.

Comment: Thanks. I have to use regex in this particular case, yeah it seems to be crashing on the srcset portion probably for some character.

Comment: It works here: https://ideone.com/NqAmHK

Comment: I changed it to /(?:<del>(.)*?<\/del>)|(?:<ins>(.)*?<\/ins>)|(?P<DOT>[\s\S])/s but still doesn't work, something in the srcset is making it crash, it matches without the srcset portion.

Comment: Yeah it works, the issue is something wierd, if i remove the last 20 characters from the img tag then it works, is there a size limit to the $match? I'm using php5.6. i'll have to investigate this further.

Comment: The preg_replace_callback manual says pcre.backtrack_limit can cause this, although that seems to be pretty large by default, I'll have to investigate further.

Comment: If you want to play with regex, use [`'/<del>[^<]*(?:<(?!\/del>)[^<]*)*<\/del>|<ins>[^<]*(?:<(?!\/ins>)[^<]*)*<\/ins>|(?P<DOT>.)/s'`](https://regex101.com/r/L8fmBr/2). Or maybe even `'/<del>[^<]*(?:<(?!\/?del>)[^<]*)*<\/del>|<ins>[^<]*(?:<(?!\/?ins>)[^<]*)*<\/ins>|(?P<DOT>.)/s'`

Comment: Hey Wiktor, Thanks. I tried your first one and that actually fixed the issue. Is the second one more efficient or what?

Comment: Oh I see the difference, yeah the first one will do. Thanks.